# Displaying a grid based map using C++ and sdl

Tags: c++, sdl, grid, roguelikes

I am trying to create a roguelike game using c++ and SDL. However, I am having trouble getting it to display the map, which is represented by a 2d array of a tile class.

Currently, my code is this:

```
for (int y = 0; y!=MAPHEIGHT; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x!=MAPWIDTH 1; x++)
    {
        apply_surface( x * TILEWIDTH, y * TILEHEIGHT, mymap[x][y].image, screen );
    }
}
```

However, running this code causes it to both dither for a while before opening the SDL window, and (usually) tell me there is an access violation.
How can I display my map?

Comment: is mapheight and mapwidth really the sizes of those arrays-1? Otherwise, you might want to try MAPHEIGHT-1 and MAPWIDTH-1. Also, have you tested and confirmed that mymap is correctly and completely filled?

Comment: @heishe: more to the point, something like `< MAPHEIGHT` is even better - semantically, the operation makes no sense for `y >= MAPHEIGHT`, not `y != MAPHEIGHT`, so it's best to code the condition as such. This is useful (for example) if you accidentally increment `y` beyond `MAPHEIGHT` within the loop: using a `!=` condition misses that kind of case entirely, and the loop will happily keep churning on through all the invalid values > `MAPHEIGHT` until it either crashes, or the int wraps back around to `MAPHEIGHT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `mymap` is really a 2-dimensions array of size `MAPWIDTH * MAPHEIGHT`. E.g. if that's a plain old array of `SDL_Surface` pointers, its declaration should be as follows:

```
SDL_Surface* mymap[MAPWIDTH][MAPHEIGHT];
```

Then all the images stored in this array have to be loaded in memory **before** you call this code. That could be a simple loop, assuming you use [SDL_image](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_image):

```
for (int x=0; x<MAPWIDTH; ++x)
{
    for (int y=0; y<MAPHEIGHT; ++y)
    {
        mymap[x][y] = IMG_Load( some_function_that_gives_an_image_path(x, y) );
        assert(mymap[x][y]); // to spot if loading fails
    }
}
```

It's very likely that you'll want to share images between different tiles, so make sure you don't mess up and that every pointer in `mymap`points to something real. A debugger might help spotting issues.

Last thing, if you're using some kind of asynchronous loading, you'll have to wait for your images to load before you start rendering them.